# Accepted answer is low scoring - Would SE benefit from a "contentious" flag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepted-answer

With respect to [Is it safe to cut off from the inside of my helmet?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/49886/19705)

This question is a good example of SE working suboptimally.  The accepted answer presently has a score of 0 with 3 up and 3 downvotes.

I suspect OP has selected this answer because it matches their original anticipated answer, where 3 answers boil down to "no don't do it" and 3 reduce to "yes its okay"

So after reading all answers, there's not a clear-cut answer.

Related but not dupes:

- [How to deal with an accepted answer that seems completely incorrect?](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1121/)

So should the question be flagged somehow to show there is no consensus and that the reader should read the whole body of answers, not just the accepted one.

Comment: People are aware of the up and down.  I have degrees in engineering and math.  Completely incorrect is your opinion.  You once posted black bikes are most stolen based on a limited sample of bikes stolen at a single school.  Do you have a degree in statistics?

Comment: @Paparazzi "completely incorrect" came from the linked related not-dupe question, and not from my wording.   Three for and three against is pretty clear there's no clear answer here.  My point is that there IS no clear answer, and whether that should be highlighted.

Comment: @Paparazzi the black bike question https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/49800/19705  was difficult but factual data was found to support the hypothesis and no factual data was found that fails to support the hypothesis.    Completely unrelated to this question.

Comment: This is not something that we can implement on Bicycles SE. It would have to be implemented on the larger Stack Exchange network. [meta.stackexchange.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com) is the place to ask for a feature like this.

Comment: @Criggie I'm curious: did you ever post this question on Meta?

Comment: @jimirings no, but have just finished.  [Here's the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303234/303287)

Answer (score 2):

In terms of answering the OP's question, no. 
In terms of leaving behind a useful document for future generations, this sounds like a good idea.